# Removing std::tuple from std::list

Tags: c++, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples and need to remove elements from the list, something like this:

```
enum class test
{
    mem1,
    mem2,
    mem3,
    mem4
};

struct A
{

};

int main()
{
    std::list<std::tuple<int, test, A>> tuple_list;

    // fill list with random objects
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        tuple_list.push_back(
               std::forward_as_tuple(i, static_cast<test>(i), A()));
    }

    // now remove it
    for (auto& ref : tuple_list)
    {
        tuple_list.remove(ref); // error C2678
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

How do I remove tuple elements from the list in above example?

**EDIT:**

I tried following method, it compiles just fine unlike previous example but there is runtime assertion:

```
int main()
{
    list<tuple<int, test, A>> tuple_list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        tuple_list.push_back(
                std::forward_as_tuple(i, static_cast<test>(i), A()));
    }

    for (auto iter = tuple_list.begin(); iter != tuple_list.end(); iter++)
    {
        tuple_list.erase(iter);
    }
}
```

> Expression: can not increment value initialized list iterator

Comment: The second one blows up because `erase` removes the iterator from the list. `iter++` is kinda invalid after that. You could `iter = tuple_list.erase(iter);` and remove the `iter++`.

Comment: man that worked!! thanks, but I'm still interested what can be done to use ranged for loop from 1st example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, **you don't want to do this**. Removing items from a `list` (or any container) in the middle of a range-based `for` is a recipe for disaster as [hidden behind the `for` loop are iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) that will be invalidated as soon as the item is removed.

This is the same problem as the second experiment with

```
for (auto iter = tuple_list.begin(); iter != tuple_list.end(); iter++)
{
    tuple_list.erase(iter); // iter rendered invalid. 
                            // That makes iter++ and iter != tuple_list.end()
                            // totally bogus.
}
```

This version can be fixed with

```
for (auto iter = tuple_list.begin(); iter != tuple_list.end(); /* nothing here */)
{
    iter = tuple_list.erase(iter); // iter updated here
}
```

or a

```
while (! tuple_list.empty()) 
{
     tuple_list.pop_front();
}
```

Or

```
tuple_list.clear();
```

## OK. On to what went wrong:

> error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

means that one of the parts of the tuple cannot be compared for equality.

```
struct A
{

};
```

has no equality operator. Solution is to add one.

```
struct A
{
}; 

bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs)
{ 
    Comparison logic goes here 
}
```

Useful additional reading:

The [Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) can be used to solve similar problems.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this, how and where do I use comparison operator?

Comment: @zebanovich I'm mid-edit. I stupidly told you how to do it without telling you not to do it because it'll blow up at runtime. `operator==` gets used for you. The error message is code deep inside `remove` looking for `==`. Have better answer up in a minute.

Comment: @user4581301 shouldn't the operator overload be inside the struct? Or does that not matter?

Comment: @OlivierSamson it can be, but the idiomatically preferred approach is to use a free function. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for explanation and further wisdom.

Comment: wait, do I just put the operator somewhere in the source file and compiler will pick it up for comparison?

Comment: So long as the operator is declared before the first time it gets used the compiler knows it exists and will use it.